# How to reduce multiple arguments in perl script

Tags: bash, perl, arguments

I am not familiar with perl and bash, but I have to use a perl script which includes bash commands to get thing done. here is the command:

```sh
basename  -t input.nii.gz -o  output \
          -g atlas1.nii.gz -l labels1.nii.gz \
          -g atlas2.nii.gz -l labels2.nii.gz \
          -g atlas3.nii.gz -l labels3.nii.gz \
          -g atlas4.nii.gz -l labels4.nii.gz \
          -g atlas3.nii.gz -l labels3.nii.gz \
          -g ............  \
          -l ............
```

I have 18 files of atlas and labels, and the command can not be executed only in the strict order.  Is it possible to reduce the arguments to following way:

```
basename  -t  input.nii.gz  -o  output -g  atlas%.nii.gz  -l  labels%.nii.gz
```

thank you.

Comment: I'm really confused...  I understand your question, but doesn't `basename` just strip the path from a file?  I didn't think it even had parameters like -t and -o.  I could be totally in left field.

Comment: That's not Perl, and bash does indeed have variables. It would look more like `atlas$i.nii.gz`

Comment: Please be more specific.  basename is command in bash, and it does not have -t, -o -g or -l options. http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename

Comment: I think `basename` is the Perl script (in which case the fact that it is written in Perl is somewhat irrelevant).

Comment: hi guys, Sorry for inconvenience, I should have been more specific.actually I am using the ANTs (advanced normalization tools ) and perl to process  a large data set.

The basename is equal to "antsMalfLabeling.sh", which is the command in ANTs, with  so much arguments like "-t input.nii.gz -o  output -g atlas1.nii.gz   -l  label1.nii.gz ....". so my question is:can I reduce about 40 arguments to 5 ? i think  chepner's answer is elegant, and I do some modification to make it work in a perl script. thank you guys. @ Hambone,@ikegami,@ Lye Heng Foo,@ chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to build up an array of arguments to use with `basename`.

```
for i in {1..18}; do
    args+=(-g atlas$i.nil.gz -l labels$i.nii.gz)
done
basename -t input.nii.gz -o output "${args[@]}"
```